# Android using clipboardManager to get the clipData but it always returns null

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

this is my code:

```
ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)accessibilityService.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        if(clipboardManager != null){
            ClipData clipData = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
            if(clipData != null){
                return text.toString();
            }
        }
```

The clipData is always null. Anything wrong?
My android device is HUAWEI with Android 10 and Android Studio 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Use  ***`clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText()`*** to get copy to clipboard text is and use ***`ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Text to copy")`*** to copy text to clipboard.This returns null because may be text is not successfully copied to clipboard.

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) mContext.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Text to Copy");
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    if (clipboard.getPrimaryClip() != null && clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText() != null) {
      // When copy to clipboard Text is not null
    } else {
      // When copy to clipboard Text is null
    }
```

Comment: But if I paste manually, text can be pasted successfully.